# mark tests that have issues in Allure reporter with cucumber-jvm adaptor as BROKEN?

Tags: cucumber-jvm, allure

Allure always set BROKEN status for tests that failed before assertion.
But often tests fail because of existing bug before assertion (like login not working).

Is there a possibility to mark tests that have issue assigned and have failed - as FAILED, not BROKEN in Allure?

Comment: Trying to parse your question. Are you asking, "If a cucumber scenario has a tag @test-has-preexisting-issue can the status be set to BROKEN instead of FAILED on any error, expected or unexpected?"

Comment: I'm asking if I can add my additional conditions to Allure to set test status FAILED when it has issue assigned

Comment: As I understand Allure, BROKEN gets set for unexpected exceptions.  You could catch all exceptions and explicitly assert failure to get the FAILED status, no?

Comment: But in this case I won't be able to separate cases when exception was caused by bug and by bad test quality.  For example: I catch NoSuchElement selenium exception. Test should be BROKEN if for example locator is bad, but test should be FAILED if absence of element is a bug => I want to mark test as FAILED when I have issue assigned

Comment: Inside the catch block you would need to decide if an assert should be invoked which is made to fail (FAILED) or if the exception is rethrown (BROKEN). The decision could be based on the tags and the nature of the failure.  You could write a class that all your catch blocks call which centralizes this logic.  Depends how much work you want to put into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to fix it in Allure adaptor and replace default one with your version.
I have done the same with java adaptor, we were need to add additional execeptions as FAILED and some description to all tests.